# Why is the strength not being shown in view cart page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically, the t1.text is a text box in my design view page and it allow user to insert a strength of coffee which is then stored in database and cookies. The database does get updated, but then why in view cart page the old figures of strength is being shown. For example, if the table is already holding strength value 5 and if you type in 10 in website in t1.text box, click on add to cart button, it will update the table but in view cart page it will show figure 5 where it should show 10. 
Help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

This is my Add to cart page code

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="t1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

                SqlCommand cmd1 = cons.CreateCommand();
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd1.CommandText = "update coffeeshop set CoffeeStrength='"+ t1.Text +"' where Id =" + id;
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is view cart page code

```
<td><%#Eval("CoffeName") %></td>
                            <td><%#Eval("CoffeeStrength") %></td>
                            <td><%#Eval("CoffeeGrind") %></td>
                            <td><%#Eval("Origin") %></td>
                            <td><%#Eval("Price") %></td>
```

Comment: Use Prepared Statements to prevent SQL Injection. Any unreliable inputs must be filtered.

Comment: i know but my question is something else

Comment: fixed tnx buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the database updates with the click and it takes and it goes with figure what was already in database